# What is android:contentDescription="@string/desc" in ImageView's xml?

Tags: android, image, accessibility

I added an `imageView` in `GraphicalLayout` but it looks different on my real device than on AVD.

I found that I need to add `contentDescription` in a layout `.xml`, but when I add: `contentDescription="@string/desc"`

there is an error:

> "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'contentDescription' with value '@string/desc')"

What is this string "desc"? What should it looks like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add it in your `string.xml` file:

```
<string name="desc">your desc goes here</string>
```

Although I don't know why you NEED to add `contentDescription` to your imageView to solve the inconsistent look problem! I don't think this will solve it.

Answer (score 43):

It's for the Accessibility Features of Android.  The `contentDescription` is what get's read back to the (assumingly blind or hard-of-sight user) so they have an idea of what the picture is since they aren't able to view it.

As to answer your question, @iturki gives the start of it.  You write the string to use for the description in `strings.xml` and give it a `name` of 'desc' or whatever your heart desires, then you set the value of `contentDescription` in the ImageView to `@string/desc`, either in the layout or programmatically.  Like I said before, it's to help users with poor eyesight get a general idea of what the image is portraying :)

Comment: It's not technically an error, it's a warning saying that the Accessibility isn't as good as it could be.  Adding a string to `contentDescription` just gives `TalkBack`, or whichever Accessibility app the user has, content to read back to describe the image, since it's not physically viewable by the impaired user.

Comment: And for purely decorative images, you can set android:contentDescription="@null" to no content description.

Answer (score 9):

That's for Accessibility (e.g., for a screen reader).  You should define a string resource that describes the image, and reference it in contentDescription.  See iturki's answer for how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

if you do not want to add desc , it will be fix by adding this line :

```
tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Content description and string description just use 
tools:ignore="ContentDescription" on your image view

Answer (score 0):

`public void setContentDescription (CharSequence contentDescription)` Defines text that briefly describes content of the view.

> A content description briefly describes the view and is primarily used for accessibility support to determine how a view should be presented to the user. In the case of a view with no textual representation, such as ImageButton, a useful content description explains what the view does. For example, an image button with a phone icon that is used to place a call may use "Call" as its content description. An image of a floppy disk that is used to save a file may use "Save".